# Найти ошибку в коде С++

Tags: c, массивы

Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку в коде, после компиляции и вывода массива на экран - программа зависает и закрывается.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include <locale.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include "stdio.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int n, m, i, j, flag, dop, g;
    printf("Введите размер матрицы\n");
    scanf_s("%d %d", &n, &m);
    int **A;
    A = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*n);
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        A[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*m);
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j<m; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            printf("%6.1d ", A[i][j]);
        }
    }
    g = m;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 2)
    {
        do
        {
            flag = 1;
            g--;

            for (j = 1; j <= m; j++)

            {
                if (A[i][j]>A[i][j + 1])
                {
                    dop = A[i][j];
                    A[i][j] = A[i][j + 1];
                    A[i][j + 1] = dop;
                    flag = 0;
                }
            }
        } while (flag == 1);

    }
    for (i = 2; i <= n; i = i + 2)
    {
        do
        {
            flag = 1;
            g--;

            for (j = 1; j <= m; j++)

            {
                if (A[i][j]<A[i][j + 1])
                {
                    dop = A[i][j];
                    A[i][j] = A[i][j + 1];
                    A[i][j + 1] = dop;
                    flag = 0;
                }
            }
        } while (flag == 1);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: У вас нет кода на C++. У вас код на C.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Классическая ошибка выхода за пределы массива...

Вы создаете `A[n][m]`, т.е. первый индекс от `0` до `n-1` включительно, второй от `0` до `m-1` включительно, а обращаетесь...

Например, `j<=m` и обращение вообще к `A[i][j+1]` - т.е. далеко за пределами.

На остальное смотреть не стал, но, может, есть и еще что...

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас есть массив, состоящий из N элементов, то допустимый диапазон индексов для этого массива `[0, N-1]`

Таким образом подобные циклы, как этот,

```
for (i = 2; i <= n; i = i + 2)
            ^^^^^^^
```

некорректны. Более того, например, в этом цикле

```
        for (j = 1; j <= m; j++)
        {
            if (A[i][j]<A[i][j + 1])
            {
                dop = A[i][j];
                A[i][j] = A[i][j + 1];
                              ^^^^^^^
                A[i][j + 1] = dop;
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
```

происходит выход за допустимый диапазон индексов, даже если вы напишите условие цикла корректно

```
for (j = 1; j < m; j++)
            ^^^^^
```

И кроме того, у вас может быть бесконечный цикл, если условие `A[i][j]>A[i][j + 1]` не выполнится ни для каких элементов строки.

```
    do
    {
        flag = 1;
        g--;

        for (j = 1; j <= m; j++)

        {
            if (A[i][j]>A[i][j + 1])
            {
                dop = A[i][j];
                A[i][j] = A[i][j + 1];
                A[i][j + 1] = dop;
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
    } while (flag == 1);
```